# Setting up routes for AMP template with category-based urls

Tags: routes

I'm stuck on implementing AMP templates with category-based URLs as I can't find a way to route the different entry types in the Routes function in the CP.

I have a channel title Articles that has two entry types (Lists and Articles) with a URL format `{businessCategory.first.slug}/{slug}` that uses a primary category for the first segment of the URL.

I've tried `*/slug/amp` as a route in the CP but then I can't change the AMP template for each entry type.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't strictly need to change the AMP template for each entry type; you can just load the entry in your AMP template via the slug in the URL.

Check out how I did it here: [Implementing AMP in Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/google-amp-should-you-care#implementing-amp-in-craft-cms)

Comment: Your article is awesome and extremely helpful! I can access the entry as you’ve indicated, but I still don’t understand how I can customize the AMP template for the two entry types that are using different templates for the non-AMP pages.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use a single _amp_entry.twig file and then use Twig embed or include for the entry type templates?

Comment: I'm suggesting you have a single _amp_entry.twig that extends from an _amp_layout.twig, yes. If you have more than one entry type, sure, just include a partial based on the entry type.